# Installshield 2010 New .net 4.0 App Pool will Upgrade all 2.0 App pools to 4.0 as well?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, installshield, application-pool

Im looking into a bug with our installshield 2010 installer. We're not doing anything complex all it does is:
- Create an IIS Virtual Directory under the Default Website
- Creates a new .net 4.0 app pool for the new Virtual Directory.

The bug is that if there is any app pools with .net 2.0 framework on the machine being installed to before the running the install, the install will automatically upgrade these to .net 4.0. The weird thing is that it wont just upgrade the original 2.0 app pool, it will take a copy of it and place "ASP.NET v4.0 .NET" + old app pool name and than assign the virtual directories that were previously pointing to the 2.0 app pool to the newly created 4.0 app pool.

This is a problem for a fair few web servers that require their older websites to be running on .NET 2.0 (example it breaks citrix).

Any ideas on why the installer would be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: How about asking in the [InstallShield forums](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/forum.php)?

Comment: How are you adding an app pool from install shield wizard? Do you know what's running in the background to create these app pools?

Comment: Hi Guys, yep have posted on installshield forums as well with no response. Have just added it under the "internet information services" branch in installshield installation designer

Answer (score 1):

Ended up getting an answer after a few weeks on the installshield forum.

http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?199006-Application-Pool-Creation-destroys-Net-applications

Was because someone had set the .net framework on the website node in installshield.

Answer (score 0):

Try use WIX tollset for installer development. It gives you more flexibility.
This is a great manual: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application